# Responsive Bootstrap lists

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website with the latest version of Bootstrap, mostly going fine besides a few small gripes.

The major one being my lists. I have two lists which work fine down to 768px wide. After that, they stack even where there is plenty of space for them to appear inline.

It's just an annoying little thing that I want sorted.

Code for my lists:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AGHicks Homepage</title>
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span5">
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>Conservatories</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Extensions</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Window & Door Refits</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Bricklaying</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Driveways</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Carpentry</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Patios</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Stonework</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span6 offset1">
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>Plastering</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Kitchen & Bathroom Refits</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Tiling</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Fencing</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Fascias</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Garages & Carports</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Guttering</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div> 
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By stacking up do you mean the text is overlapping? If that's the case, you could use media queries to change the size of the typography as the screen size changes.

See the fiddle below and resize (make smaller) the bottom right pane to see the font size change.

Sample code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    body { font-size:120%;}
    .wrap {max-width:770px;}
}  

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body { font-size:100%;}
}   

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body { font-size:75%;}
}
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SAzm8/)